# separating the images and text content from Wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress post which I would like to strip the images and text content out in 2 separate parts. I wan't to be able to control both elements separately.

current attempt

```
<?php
    $content = wpautop($content); // Add paragraph-tags
    $content = str_replace('<p></p>', '', $content); // remove empty paragraphs
    $content = preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content); // remove paragraphs around img tags
    echo $content;
?>
```

I was able to put

tags on the content but ot sure how to take out elements and bring each type back

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to grab all `img` tags:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($content);
$images = $document->getElementsByTagName('img');
```

Comment: ok, but I need to post the content without the images and post the content in another place with just the images. And I thought I was just removing empty p tags with my code.

Comment: @user3550879 my bad, you're correct about removing empty tags.