# pull out images in wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress

Looking to automatically separate the images and text from my wordpress post `<?php the_content(); ?>` so I can put them in two different locations.

Not sure the best method to do this but have  tried preg_replace approach but cant seem to figure out the right input

```
<?php
 // get the content
 $block = get_the_content();

 // check and retrieve blockquote
if(preg_match ...
```

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's answered here on [wordpress.stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162162/how-to-remove-images-from-showing-in-a-post-with-the-content).

```
$content = get_the_content();
$content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", " ", $content);          
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
echo $content;
```

To get the images from the inline post content this [article](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/192614/how-to-get-all-inline-images-in-post-content) will help.

```
preg_match('#(<img.*?>)#', $content, $results);
```

Comment: This removes the images from the content. But the post doesn;t say how to put the pictures in another location

Comment: Google man, plenty of help already around https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/192614/how-to-get-all-inline-images-in-post-content

Comment: I used google, but it all says to use docs instead of preg_replace

Comment: I believe what they were referring to a more complex way but easier in terms of making the site run better

Comment: Send me the link please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470868/separating-the-images-and-text-content-from-wordpress-post, shows another example of what I tried to do

Comment: Yes you could do that but you'd have to restrict it to the <article> tag where the content of the post is.  I don't think this method would be any faster but might be easier to loop over the image to reposition them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a new function with the_content() to filter media and string from post content.

To do it,   You should to know php well.

Comment: As mentioned below, I was wondering if there was an option where I wouldn't have to do it twice to put the images and content in two spots (run a function to look for images in one sot, then run a similar one to pull out images)