# Displaying post images only

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to put just the images that are in my Wordpress post on screen. I have the following code which removes them and posts just the text

```
    <?php 
        $content = get_the_content();
        $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", " ", $content);          
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
        $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
        echo $content;
    ?>
```

I'm basically trying to do the same thing but pull out and post just the images.  These code(s) would appear on the same page so I'm not sure if it's possible to write one function to 'separate' the images and text and echo them n different divs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pull out images in wordpress post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48980397/pull-out-images-in-wordpress-post)

Comment: If you dont `preg_replace` but `preg_match` it, it should be possible

Comment: Instead of trying to strip it out, why not specifically just put the image onto the page? Seems more work to be using regex.

Comment: I don't have control over what images get put in/out as it is a Wordpress theme. The post gets put on the page through php content